# R: Write to file without trailing newline

Tags: r

I'm trying to write values to separate files (to include them in my TeX file). But all of the methods I stubled across insert a new line at the end of the file (which results into an undesired space down the road). The manual (e.g. `?write`) didn't provide any helpful information either.

```
# 1st try
write(x = "1", file = "test")

# 2nd try
fileConn<-file("test")
writeLines(c("1"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Thanks! Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cat` for this:

```
cat("1", file = "test.txt")
```

In this case, as you can see, it does not add a newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want to write the file in binary mode, when you open the connection.

```
text = c("a", "b", "c")
file_connection = file(file_path, open='wb')
writeLines(text = text, con = file_connection)
close(file_connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write multiple lines and avoid trailing (last) newline, you can use `cat` in two steps - first write all but last lines and then the last one:

```
x = c("a", "b", "c")
cat(x[1:length(x)-1], file = "test.txt", append = F, sep = "\n")
cat(x[length(x)]    , file = "test.txt", append = T, sep = "")
```